# Is it possible to offset a plot using ezplot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to offset a plot after plotting using ezplot in x- direction by 10 units.

```
syms x y;
f1= x^2 + y^2 - (6*y/5)-1/16;
h = ezplot(f1,[-.25 .25 0 1.25]);
```

I am unable to resolve this issue on my own. Any help or links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can do that other than manually offsetting the plot yourself in `f1` by:

```
syms x y;
f1 = (x - 10)^2 + y^2 - (6*y/5) - 1/16; % Shift x coordinate to the right by 10
h = ezplot(f1, [10-0.25 10+0.25 0 1.25]); % Note the shift in the x limits
```

Remember that `ezplot`'s job is to plot an equation for you.  You can't simply shift the points when you're done plotting.... actually you can't really do that with any of the MATLAB plot mechanisms because the job is simply to either plot points in arrays or matrices, or in your case for `ezplot` to plot the equations.